# Prove that : $\dfrac{d}{dx}(\log_2 x + \log_x 2)\ = \frac {\ln 2x(\ln x/2)} { \ln 2^{x} (lnx)^2}$.

Tags: derivatives

Well tried this but still stuck on how to differentiate a log.

> Prove that :
>
> $$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\log_2 x + \log_x 2\right) = \frac {\ln 2x(\ln x/2)} { \ln 2^{x} (\ln x)^2}$$

Comment: This is unreadable! What is y? Do you mean a differential equation?

Comment: I think he wants $\frac{dy}{dx}( log_{2}{x}+log_{x}{2})$

Comment: i have updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Sean Roberson idea.

$$(\log_{2}{x})'=\frac{1}{x \ln 2}$$

$$(\log_{x}{2})'=\left(\frac{\ln 2}{\ln x}\right)'=\ln(2)\left(\frac{1}{\ln x}\right)'=\frac{-\ln 2}{x \ln^2(x)}$$

To prove your edited equality:

$$\frac{1}{x \ln 2}-\frac{\ln 2}{x \ln^2(x)}=\frac{\ln^2(x)-\ln^2(2)}{x\ln2\ln^2(x)}=\frac{(\ln x-\ln 2)(\ln x+\ln 2)}{\ln2^x \ln^2(x)}$$

I think you can take it from here.

Comment: i have updated my post

Comment: @gammastester , can you help me prove my question please

Comment: @lutaaya-huzaifah-idris: This answer gives you all the basic infomation to complete your question. Where do you have problems?

Comment: Thanks so much @valer

Answer (score 1):

I won't try to mess with the formatting, but here's the general rule.

Remember that through the change of base formula, $\log_b x = \frac{\ln x}{\ln b}$. Taking derivatives shows that

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \frac{\ln x}{\ln b} = \frac{1}{x\ln b} $$

meaning you'll scale by the natural logarithm of the base. We also note

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \log_x k = -\frac{\ln k}{x (\ln x)^2} $$

which follows from the quotient rule. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Man nice explanation but help me in editing am still fighting with editing

Comment: i have updated my post

Comment: Please proceed with your solution

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris It is rude of you to ask him to provide you full solution or give any hints because you have not told us what is your problem. As far as I can see, he gave enough information to you to solve the question.

Comment: differentiaing the second log is my problem @A---B

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris See Sean's solution again. He did show how to differentiate a log function when base is variable.